# Source code output is not indented correctly using \n with php and pdo

Tags: php, html, pdo

If I output the lines normally without `\n` everything is outputted on the same line in the source code which is not very nice looking.

So I'm wondering If there Is a fix for the problem at hand here.

The first line gets indented correctly but the lines coming after It gets stuck to the left wall without indentation as the code sample states below.

Source code:

```
               <div><img u="image" src="images/Wooden_skull.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" src="images/Lion.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" src="images/cat.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" src="images/Here_we_go.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" src="images/ruined_building.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" src="images/DSC_0184.JPG" /></div>
<div><img u="image" src="images/Dragon.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" src="images/Punk_Tron.jpg" /></div>
<div><img u="image" src="images/Baby_viking.jpg" /></div>
```

PHP Code:

```
foreach($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $sliderimages .= '<div><img u="image" src="images/'.$row['image'].'" /></div>' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: That is expected, because each output line starts directly with `<div>`, no preceding whitespace. PHP has no idea about how you want your HTML formatted -- it only writes out text (which happens to be HTML).  This is one of those things that if you really and truly care about, you have to take care to make it work yourself. It isn't PHP's job, and the browser doesn't care either.

Comment: If the first line is indented, it is not due to this code - it's because the preceding output already sent the indentation whitespace earlier in your code,

Comment: The "fix" is to just put the whitespace in there `$sliderimages .= "\t\t<div><img....\n";`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've heard a rumor about messing too much with source code is bad for SEO though, do you think something like the quick fix would have an issue with SEO? Since my friend is simply a user it would not be too wise letting him go nuts in the files and it also saves him a lot of time having the site being manageable through an admin page and output it with the database.

Comment: Manipulating whitespace had sure better not have any effect on seo. It's true that manipulating meta keywords and similar tactics are taken into account by search engines, but whitespace is totally irrelevant to everyone and everything except the human viewing it. The machines certainly don't care (actually, the machines like fewer extra spaces, because that means fewer bytes to transfer)

Comment: If you view most large sites (where you can see static HTML, rather than script driven code) you'll mostly find that the HTML is minimized to remove _all_ unnecessary whitespace, so that it is as compressed as possible for transmission. The browser just needs the tag structure after all.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Alright, thanks a lot for your assistance and for taking time to answer my questions!

Answer (score 0):

To create an indent in the source code (but not in the web page) in PHP, use `\t`.

Using this:

```
foreach($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $sliderimages .= '\t\t<div><img u = "image" src = "images/' . $row['image'] .'" /></div>' . "\n";
}
```

Should produce this output:

```
               <div><img u = "image" src = "images/Wooden_skull.jpg" /></div>
               <div><img u = "image" src = "images/Lion.jpg" /></div>
               <div><img u = "image" src = "images/cat.jpg" /></div>
               <div><img u = "image" src = "images/Here_we_go.jpg" /></div>
               <div><img u = "image" src = "images/ruined_building.jpg" /></div>
               <div><img u = "image" src = "images/DSC_0184.JPG" /></div>
               <div><img u = "image" src = "images/Dragon.jpg" /></div>
               <div><img u = "image" src = "images/Punk_Tron.jpg" /></div>
               <div><img u = "image" src = "images/Baby_viking.jpg" /></div>
```